# Error in data conversion from model to view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Hi I am getting error in enumerating the value which is returned from a SP.

```
ViewBag.hdnFOPSectorID = formc["hdnFOPSectorID"];//formc["hdnFOPSectorID"].Split('&');
ViewData["filterflight"] = oRep.GetSearchFltFilterDetails(WebUtility.FormatDate(formc["txtFromDate"].ToString()), WebUtility.FormatDate(formc["txtToDate"].ToString()), TimeSpan.Parse(formc["txtFromTime"]), TimeSpan.Parse(formc["txtToTime"]), strFAAGroup, plant_center_id).Distinct().ToList();
```

This is My code. Here i am getting the exception that

"The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once"

Please answer me as soon as possible.

Comment: Where do you get values for `strFAAGroup` and `plant_center_id` from? If your method returns `IQueryable` you can call `ToList()` to explicitly enumerate your query first and only then call `.Distinct()`

Comment: Those values will get from DB.  .GetSearchFltFilterDetails is an SP . It will get the values. SP is working fine as i tested it seperately.

Comment: can any body help me?